# Changing the black background to white when an HTML element is viewed in Full Screen Mode

Tags: html, background, screen, element

I have a function that will view an HTML element in Full Screen mode.

The view always has a black background and I can't read text.

How can I change that background to white for these elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: white;
   }
```

That's it. A white background for all full screen loads of anything. It works in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.